# How to align box at half bottom and half out of container

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I am solving a challenge and i am **unable to fix a box at bottom header where half box will be inside header and the other half will be out of header with fully responsive**. I tried it do with positions and bottom but when i change responsiveness more than half portion of box goes inside header or sometime more than half portion goes outside of header. i want that box size always fix at half inside bottom.

i want to align box like this:

[image: click here to see image]

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet that you are currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `position: relative` on the parent element
2. Apply `position: absolute` to the child element
3. Place the child element below the parent element by using `top: 100%`
4. offset the child element to 50% of its own height to the top by using `transform: translateY(-50%)`

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}




/* for visualization purpose only */
.parent {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 30vh;
}

.child {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  min-height: 15vh;
  width: 40vw;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Parent
  <div class=child>Child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work:

##### With `position: absolute`:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50%;
}
```

##### With `transform`:

```
.box {
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

Edit:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) // i am not sure if -50% or 50%
}
```

Comment: It will not work as intended. I move your exact code to a snippet. Posting your code as a snippet adds value as evidence and you could self-validate that your answer work (or in this case do not work)